# JMeter Scenario Test

Tags: web-services, rest, jmeter

I want to test web services under single .jmx file.And that particular .jmx file more than one services is their under single services more than one thread is their. My question is that if one test failed don't go the next services or scenario? Is possible in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Please set thread group as below:

[image]

Comment: if i apply stop thread then will go to next i want condition like that if passed then go if not then stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with the following condition:

```
${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

**JMeterThread.last_sample_ok** is a [pre-defined variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars), its value is `true` if previous sample result is successful and `false` in the opposite case so you can use it do define whether If Controller's children will be executed or not.

[image: JMeter If Controller example]

In the above example `Sampler 2` will be executed only if `Sampler 1` is successful

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) article for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Could please upload some screen shot step by step I am new to JMeter